# Jquery/Ajax return data but doesn't alert

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

I have these code:

show.php:

```
<div id="show" style="background-color: white; color: #2b2b2b "></div>
<script>

    $(document).ready(function(){
        $('#btnsearch').click(function(){
            var key = {
                'command': 'search',
                'data': $("#inputsearch").val()
            };
            $.ajax({
                type: 'POST',
                url: 'query.php',
                data: key,
                dataType: 'json',
                    success: function(msg){
                        $('#show').html(msg);
            }
            })
        });
    });

</script>
```

and query.php:

```
$command = $_SESSION['command'];
if($command == 'search'){
    $db = Db::getInstance();
    $str = $_POST['data'];
    $records = $db->query("SELECT * FROM m_cinfo LEFT OUTER JOIN m_jinfo ON m_cinfo.cinfo_id=m_jinfo.cinfo_id where fullName LIKE '%$str%'");

    //echo json_encode($records, JSON_UNESCAPED_UNICODE);
    echo 'تست';
}
```

Parrams and Responce are correct and input text + search send to query.php and تست returns but nothing shows in my div. It doesn't even alert anything in the success area.

2. if i uncomment echo json_encode($records, JSON_UNESCAPED_UNICODE);, is the way correct to retrieve json data?

Like i want to use the data from my db. what should i do? i get json like this:

```
[{"cinfo_id":"1","fullName":"علی علوی","phone":"09151234576","mail":"ali.Alavi@gmail.com","description":"در نمایشگاه آشنا شدیم","jinfo_id":"1","jobTitle":"شرکت","jobName":"بازرگانی","city":"مشهد"}]
```

and echo that but when i say

```
$('#show').html(msg.fullName);
```

for example, nothing would show.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: You misunderstood the option `dataType` which is (according to documentation) `the type of data that you're expecting back from the server`. So your PHP should echo/print JSON instead of expecting JSON from the javascript client

Comment: Or maybe I misunderstood you ... then the answer to your question `2.` would be NO

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That's because ajax expects json response and the query.php script does not return json.
If you add error callback to your ajax you will see that it's triggered.

```
$.ajax({
            type: 'POST',
            url: 'query.php',
            data: key,
            dataType: 'json',
            success: function(msg){
                $('#show').html(msg);
            },
            error: function (err) {
                console.log(err);
            }
```

To fix this in your query.php you should echo json_encoded string like this

```
echo json_encode(array('message' => 'تست'));
```

And then in your success callback you can access the message like this

```
success: function(response){
            $('#show').html(response.message);
}
```

Update: okay if your $db->query method returns json as string then you can do the following

```
$records = $db->query("SELECT * FROM m_cinfo LEFT OUTER JOIN m_jinfo ON m_cinfo.cinfo_id=m_jinfo.cinfo_id where fullName LIKE '%$str%'");

$decoded = json_decode($records, true);

echo json_encode($decoded);
```

Note that your query is vulnerable to [SQL injection](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_injection) . You should escape the $str variable or use prepared statements. For example if somebody enters this string in the search field it could drop your 'm_cinfo' table

```
somestring'; DROP TABLE m_cinfo; #
                                 ^ this will comment the rest of your query
```

Comment: on top of that it should be `$_POST['command']` rather than `$_SESSION['command']` as `command` is part of the POST-Request-Body

Comment: Ah yes, you're correct. I didn't even bother to look at code above since OP said that the response is being returned.

Comment: Thanks that worked.
Now if i want to use the data from my db what should i do?
i get json like this:
[{"cinfo_id":"1","fullName":"علی علوی","phone":"09151234576","mail":"ali.Alavi@gmail.com","description":"در نمایشگاه آشنا شدیم","jinfo_id":"1","jobTitle":"شرکت","jobName":"بازرگانی","city":"مشهد"}]
and echo that but when i say 
 $('#show').html(msg.fullName); for example, nothing would show.

Comment: What does actually `$db->query('/**/'')` return? If it's an array json_encode() will work.

Comment: Thanks memo for all you help. I appreciate it :)

Comment: I'm using $str as the element to search:  where fullName LIKE '%$str%'"
is my db still vulnerable? it's a select statement.
The how should i make it secure?

Comment: The least you can do is escape $str with mysql_real_escape_string like this `$str = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['data']);` . But note that this function is deprecated in php 5.5 and removed in php7. The better solution would be to use prepared statements like PDO or Mysqli prepared statements